# MDI Application Reports a Hidden Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, hidden, mdi

I have an MDI application in VB.NET. I want to run a function only if no other forms are open - just the main form. So I test the Application.OpenForms.Count before running the function, wanting no more than 1 open form (the main form) to be open.

With only the main form open, I test the Application.OpenForms.Count and get 2. So, knowing I have no other forms open, I iterate the forms and try to retrieve all the forms' names. The main form reports, but the hidden one does not. Neither does it report a "text" (form caption) value.

Then I tested both forms' sizes: height and width, both report values. Similarly, location x & y report valid values. When I try to set the hidden form to visible or show it, I see nothing. Then I commanded BringToFront. The Visual Studio IDE comes to the front.

My question is: does the IDE count as a form in a running application inside the IDE in debug mode? If so, how then to write a proper test in the code to limit the Application.OpenForms.Count to 1 when running the compiled and installed application?

Comment: Are you using an ACTUAL MDI interface? *Lot's of people use the term MDI incorrectly.  If you are using the actual MDI interface where you have a main MdiParent with MdiChildren contained within, then ask your main MDI form how many [MdiChildren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) it has?

Comment: You'll have to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- For that, build a new MDI Application, add code that can reproduce the behavior you're describing and post it here, along with the VS IDE version and any other details that clarify the context.

Comment: Yes, actual MDI with child forms. And the MdiChildren count did the trick.